# Talend : tMongoDBInput - how Use an input field in a tMongoDBInput?

Tags: mongodb, talend

In my Talend job, I have a first step to select a data in a database postgres.

[image]

After this selection, I would like to use the value of this field, in a parameter in an aggregation pipeline query :

[image]

How I can use it please ? I have tested `context.LastStartOperation` and `LastStartOperation`, and `input_row.LastStartOperation` without success.

What is the well syntax please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a tFlowToIterate between tDBInput and tMongoDBInput like this:

```
tDBInput -- Row -- tFlowToIterate -- Iterate -- tMongoDBInput
```

Then you can access the value like this in your tMongoDBInput:

`rowX.LastStartOperation` where rowX is the row between tDBInput and tFlowToIterate